# AttributeError After processing the view

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, django-views

After Submitting the like button data is successfuly updating with the database but after this step it won't redirecting to the successful url. instead of that it is throwing attribute error. If I use `HttpResponseRedirect('/album/')` instaed of successful url this error is not comming. [Please refer this link for the traceback](http://dpaste.com/22227PB)

### models.py

Codes in models.py

```
class VoteManager(models.Manager):

    def get_vote_or_unsaved_blank_vote(self,song,user):
        try:
            return Vote.objects.get(song=song,user=user)

        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return Vote.objects.create(song=song,user=user)

class Vote(models.Model):
    UP = 1
    DOWN = -1
    VALUE_CHOICE = ((UP, "️"),(DOWN, "️"),)


    like = models.SmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True, choices=VALUE_CHOICE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    song = models.ForeignKey(Song, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    voted_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    objects = VoteManager()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('user', 'song')
```

### views.py

codes in views.py

```
class SongDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Song
    template_name = 'song/song_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
        ctx = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            vote = Vote.objects.get_vote_or_unsaved_blank_vote(song=self.object, user = self.request.user)
            vote_url = reverse('music:song_vote_create', kwargs={'song_id':vote.song.id})
            vote_form = SongVoteForm(instance=vote)
            ctx['vote_form'] = vote_form
            ctx['vote_url'] = vote_url
        return ctx

class SongVoteCreateView(View):
    form_class = SongVoteForm
    context = {}

    def get_success_url(self,**kwargs):
        song_id = self.kwargs.get('song_id')
        return reverse('music:song_detail', kwargs={'pk':song_id})

    def post(self,request,pk=None,song_id=None):
        user = self.request.user
        song_obj = Song.objects.get(pk=song_id)
        vote_obj,created = Vote.objects.get_or_create(song = song_obj,user = user) 
        vote_form = SongVoteForm(request.POST, instance=vote_obj)

        if vote_form.is_valid():
            new_vote = vote_form.save(commit=False)
            new_vote.user = self.request.user
            new_vote.save()
            return new_vote
```

### song_detail.html

codes in html page.

```
        <form action="{{vote_url}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ vote_form.as_p }}
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" >Vote</button>
        </form>
```

### Error code

[Please refer this link for the traceback](http://dpaste.com/22227PB)

`'Vote' object has no attribute 'get'`

Comment: aside of GwybBleidDs answer, which is right: you can avoid the trouble using the form_valid method instead the post method: see the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#basic-forms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `post` method needs to return an HttpResponse, not a Vote object.

But you shouldn't be defining `post` in the first place. All that code should go in `form_valid`.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    user = self.request.user
    song_obj = Song.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['song_id'])
    vote_obj, _ = Vote.objects.get_or_create(song = song_obj, user = user) 
    form.instance = vote_obj
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

Note, you don't need to check `is_valid`, and you also don't need to set the user as you've already done that in `vote_obj`.

Comment: Mr.Daniel Thank you for your answer, I have changed the code as you suggested but now it is throwing another error. `[30/Oct/2019 11:15:15] "POST /album/song_vote_create/1/ HTTP/1.1" 405 0` can you please help me with this.

Comment: Your SongCreateView should actually inherit from CreateView, not View.\

Answer (score 1):

You are returning `Vote` object from `post` method in your `SongVoteCreateView` view. You should return `Response` instead. Django doesn't know what to do with model object returned from a view.

Comment: I have added `return reverse('music:song_detail', kwargs={'pk':song_id})` as response but it is not working. it is throwing another error like this `'str' object has no attribute 'get'`